# Can we Customize SharePoint Modern app bar

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-extension

Can we customize the newly introduced App Bar in SharePoint online Modern pages using Extension? Like adding a new icon.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible, as this is a DOM element.
Suggest you to clone one of the icons and append it to app bar. Note, that icon also has an event for handling clicks, so this one will need to be re-added - basically copy onClick event from one of the icons, and add it to your new icon.